# What can we infer about the discrete distribution $P(X \ge x) = {x^{- E(X)}}$ for every natural $x$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

A discrete probability distribution has the following property

$$
P(X \ge x) = {x^{- E(X)}}
$$

where $x$ is a positive natural number and $E(X)$ is the finite expected value of the distribution. This is a power law distribution where the exponent turns out to be the expected value of the distribution.

**Question**: I am trying to find if there is an interpretation of this distribution i.e. what does it signify when the exponent happens to be the expected value. Is there anything that is significant or non trivial about such a distribution.

**Edit**: Math1000 has given a numerical answer which is correct. Actually prior to posting this question, I had done the same calculation using the zeta function and obtained the same unique answer. However, what I was looking for in my question is the **interpretation** of this distribution, may be something like a physical interpretation if at all it exits. To see where I am coming form, I observed this distribution in economic data. So while zeta function gives a numerical fit, I wanted to see if I can explain the distribution in the layman (economic) sense.

Note: I have posted this question at [Stats SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237996/what-can-we-infer-about-the-probability-distribution-px-ge-x-x-ex).

Comment: "Note: I have posted this question at Stats SE." And you should not have done that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Computing $\mathbb E[X]$ we find that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X\geqslant n)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-\mathbb E[X]}\\
&=\zeta(\mathbb E[X]),
\end{align}
where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. Since $\zeta$ is decreasing, this equation has a unique solution and Wolfram Alpha gives its numerical value $\mathbb E[X]\approx 1.8338$.

Comment: Since $P(X \ge 1) = {1^{- E(X)}}=1$, I think you can take $\mathbb P(X \ge 1)=1$

Comment: @Henry Good point.